# Preventing OpenOCD from modifying padding after .ARM.exidx section

Tags: linker, arm, checksum, bare-metal, openocd

I'm trying to fix code checksum mismatch for an image running on a bare metal ARM system. A script in the build system calculates the checksum and embeds it into the image. The flashed software calculates the checksum of the memory and compares it to the embedded value. When OpenOCD is used, the checksums are different. It turns out there is an 8-byte gap between sections named `.ARM.exidx` and `.data` that OpenOCD decides to fill with `0xFF`. The build script is not even aware of sections, it works on segments, that data lies in the middle of a segment and it's filled by `0x00` (apparently by the linker). I have found several workarounds, but all of them feel imperfect.

One category of workarounds is to make OpenOCD and the linker use the same padding byte.

I can instruct OpenOCD to use `0x00` as the fill byte using the `flash padded_value 0 0` command. It can be added to the OpenOCD command line (it has to go after `init`) or to the gdb command line (prefixed by `monitor` and inserted between `target` and `load`). Then I'll have to make sure that everybody is using the updated scripts. I wish I could tell OpenOCD to stop messing with my data, but apparently there is no such command.

I was thinking of changing the checksum calculating script to look for gaps between sections and fill them with `0xFF`, but it's too complex and would break if somebody configures OpenOCD to fill the gaps with `0x00`.

Another category of workarounds is to shuffle sections around so that the unaligned end of `.ARM.exidx` either stands at the end of the checksummed region or is followed by a section that doesn't need alignment. That's possible, but seems rather intrusive. We are using scripts from the board vendor, and changing them too heavily could be risky.

The third category of workarounds is to fill the gaps by expanding or adding sections so that OpenOCD won't see them.

I tried adding alignment to the `.ARM.exidx` section:

```
  .ARM.exidx :
  {
    *(.ARM.exidx* .gnu.linkonce.armexidx.*)
    . = ALIGN (0x10);
  } >ram AT>rom
```

No luck, the linker says ".ARM.exidx has both ordered and unordered sections". It actually fails only if the alignment would move the current address.

I was able to add a separate `.fill` section after `.ARM.exidx`:

```
  .fill :
  {
    BYTE(0xFF)
    . = ALIGN(0x10);
  } >ram AT>rom =0xFF
```

I can use any value to fill, the section would prevent OpenOCD from changing the image. One thing that doesn't feel right is that the section adds 16 bytes if it's not needed, i.e. when `.ARM.exidx` happens to be 16-byte aligned. I cannot remove `BYTE`, the linker would discard the section. The `KEEP` keyword seems to apply to input sections only.

That's the solution I like most, but I hope maybe there is a better approach.

Comment: what if you just use objcopy -O binary and use the bin file with openocd, it is fine with binary or elf.  And pad the bin file as needed to an even boundary so that openocd wont be tempted to do any more padding...

Comment: multiple ways to take openocd out of the equation.

Comment: is there a reason to keep exidx?

Comment: @old_timer: No need to keep exidx, I was wrongly assuming it would break stack unwinding in the debugger. The debugger is OK. I believe removing exidx would only break the code that unwinds stack on its own, but I don't have such code. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of BYTE(), use FILL().

```
.fill (LOAD) :
  {
    FILL(0xFFFF);
    . = ALIGN(0x10);
  } >ram AT>rom =0xFF
```

If the section is not needing alignment, it should take zero size.

Comment: Sadly, the linker would make the .fill section non-loadable even if alignment is needed. As a result, OpenOCD would ignore it and fill the gap with 0xFF, breaking the checksum.

Comment: You can add modifiers to the sections to make them loadble.  I updated another modifier is (READONLY), but it sounds like you decided just to remove the 'idx' completely.

Comment: My linker (GNU ld (xPack GNU Arm Embedded GCC x86_64) 2.36.1.20210621) doesn't support LOAD or READONLY. I tried NOLOAD, DSECT, COPY, INFO and OVERLAY - neither gives the desired effect. Indeed, I'm going to discard the .ARM.exidx section. It should probably be asked separately how to make a loadable align section that can shrink to 0. This question is too unfocused, sorry.

Comment: @proski  That is real life :)